# Android Studio - TextView Not updating after change has been made in database

Tags: java, android, json, xml, textview

I'm new in this kind of thing and I've encounterd a problem that I cannot find a solution for it, so I've come here to ask for your help.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Register a new user in database
2. Check if it works.
3. Change the user or pass
4. Display the changed username on app.

Sadly, step 4 doesn't work. Let's say that I register user and password 123, 123. I check them to make sure it works (login from app), logout from app, go to database tables, edit the user to 321 return to app. Login with user 321 and password 123. In MainActivity the display will be the same as the first one , user/pass 123 instead of user 321 and pass 123.

Here is the part that handles the user/pass from MainActivity class

```
  txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name); //name
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
  //  setting toolbar
    Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);


    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    String name = AppController.getString(getApplicationContext(), "name"); //name
    String email = AppController.getString(getApplicationContext(), "email");
    txtName.setText(name); //name
    txtEmail.setText(email);
```

The problem I'm facing is that the username doesn't update after changes have been made to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put that code in the onResume method of MainActivity. The onCreate method is not always called when you return to your activity.

Comment: It did not helped me, adding the code in the onResume method simply resumed the mainactivity after running the app. The username that should be displayed in MainActivity is still the old one ( not the same as it currently is in database).

Comment: EDIT: Maybe this could help your understand my problem a little bit better. [link](http://i.imgur.com/Aoi4EWq.png)

Comment: I suppose AppControler.getString() retrieves the name from the SharedPreferences, not from your database. Do you update this value ?

Comment: Yes you are right, it retrieves the name from the SharedPreferences, and as I can see it does update the value in app controller with sp.edit().putString(key, value).commit();.
[sessionmanager](http://pastebin.com/00Sam6kc)
[appcontroller](http://pastebin.com/GnU7LX4c)